# random graph and bfs in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

```
import networkx as nw
g=nw.random_regular_graph(3,10)
f=nw.dfs_tree(g,0)
print f
```

I want to generate a random graph and use BFS to obtain the diameter of the graph. I use above code but nothing displayed. What's the problem here? New to Python, hope someone could help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get anything displayed by `print` a Graph.

Suppose you intend to display every edge of `f`:

```
>>> g = nw.random_regular_graph(3, 10)
>>> f = nw.dfs_tree(g, 0)
>>> f
<networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph object at 0x00000000030AA128>
>>> f.edges()
[(0, 9), (1, 3), (1, 7), (2, 1), (4, 6), (5, 4), (6, 2), (8, 5), (9, 8)]
```

Read the [NetworkX Tutorial](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.8/_downloads/networkx_tutorial.pdf) and you'll gain basic knowledge of how to use networkx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the graph, you should use the Networkx function [draw()](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html). This function should be used with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).

So, here is your code with added function to display the graph:

```
import networkx as nw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g=nw.random_regular_graph(3,10)
f=nw.dfs_tree(g,0)

nw.draw(g)
plt.show()
```

This code gives this following graph:

[image]

Read the links I provided you in order to personalize what you want to display in the graph.